# Half transaction execution in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, code-first

I have the following models:

```
public class CardAccount
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4)]        
    public string CardPIN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal CardCash { get; set; }
}
```

-

```
[Table("TransactionHistory")]
public class TransactionHistory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = false)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]                
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Ammount { get; set; }
}
```

Database Context:

```
public class ATMDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ATMDbContext()
        : base("ATM")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ATMDbContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public IDbSet<CardAccount> CardAccounts { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<TransactionHistory> TransactionHistory { get; set; }
}
```

And an ATM class with a withdraw method:

```
public class ATMClient
{
    private const int CardNumberLength = 10;
    private const int CardPINLength = 4;

    private ATMDbContext dbContext;
    private IOutputProvider outputProvider;

    public ATMClient(ATMDbContext dbContext)
        : this(dbContext, new ConsoleOutputProvider())
    {
    }

    public ATMClient(ATMDbContext dbContext, IOutputProvider outputProvider)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.outputProvider = outputProvider;
    }

    public void WithdrawMoney(string cardNumber, string cardPIN, decimal money)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cardNumber))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The card number is null.");
        }

        if (cardNumber.Length != CardNumberLength)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The card number is invalid. Please, state a proper {0} digit card number.", CardNumberLength));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cardPIN))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The card pin is null.");
        }

        if (cardPIN.Length != CardPINLength)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("The card pin is invalid. Please, state a proper {0} digit card pin.", CardPINLength));
        }

        if (money < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid amount to withdraw. Please, state a valid positive number.");
        }

        using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
        {
            var currentAccount = dbContext.CardAccounts.Where(x => x.CardNumber == cardNumber).FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                if (currentAccount == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid card number.");
                }

                if (currentAccount.CardPIN != cardPIN)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid pin number.");
                }

                if (currentAccount.CardCash < money)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Insufficient funds.");
                }

                currentAccount.CardCash -= money;

                var transactionLog = new TransactionHistory();
                transactionLog.CardNumber = cardNumber;
                transactionLog.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;
                transactionLog.Ammount = money;

                dbContext.TransactionHistory.Add(transactionLog);

                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                outputProvider.PrintLine(ex.Message);
                transaction.Rollback();
            }

            //transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I uncomment 'transaction.Commit()' everything works fine. However, when it is commented, the update statement executes but the transactionLog is not added to the database. How is the update statement commited without the transaction commit? Is SaveChanges commiting the transaction prematurely?

Here is the code I am using:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dbContext = new ATMDbContext();
        var atm = new ATMClient(dbContext);

        var account = dbContext.CardAccounts.Where(x => x.CardCash >= 10000).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(account.CardNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(account.CardCash);

        atm.WithdrawMoney(account.CardNumber, account.CardPIN, 10000m);

        Console.WriteLine(account.CardNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(account.CardCash);

        var transactionHistory = dbContext.TransactionHistory.Where(x => x.CardNumber == account.CardNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(transactionHistory.CardNumber);
    }
```

This leads to NullReferenceException as already mentioned:

```
    var transactionHistory = dbContext.TransactionHistory.Where(x => x.CardNumber == account.CardNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(transactionHistory.CardNumber);
```

Output:

```
2504478325
21835.56
2504478325
11835.56
```

---

EDIT:

Okay, a little more information:
It seems

```
currentAccount.CardCash -= money;
```

doesn't actually modify the actual record. When you check the value in the database, it is the old one. However, the value printed on the console is decremented, even if I try to get the object from the database again by using

```
account = dbContext.CardAccounts.Where(x => x.CardNumber == account.CardNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

before the second card info printing.

---

EDIT 2:

The deviation comes from the context itself. The value in the context is modified while the value in the database is not. How can the invalid state of the context be evaded(except removing the transaction..)? Is the recreation of the context the only solution?

Comment: Why are you using a transaction in the WithdrawMoney method?

Comment: Well, for one stop swallowing errors. This practice can lead to the app limping along in a strange state and cause all kinds of strange writes. I'll revisit this question when you have fixed that.

Comment: @usr Sorry, I didn't get the point.

Comment: In case of an error the code continues to run, probably in a broken state. Better throw; the exception to make sure the behavior you are seeing is not causes by that.

Comment: Aside note : [StringLength(4)] public string CardPIN { get; set; } implies that you store people cards passwords in plain text! If this is going to be in production one day you better hash that with salt and make it 32 chars string (salted), because if your db gets in to the wrong hands you and your company will be in deep trouble. :)

Comment: It is a sample coursework project. The whole idea of the system is to grasp the concept of transactions. That's the reason I NEED to use a transaction in the withdraw method!

Comment: @usr, the problem does not come from the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to create a transaction to your escenario. I think is more easy do this:

```
using (var dbContext = new ATMDbContext())
{
    var currentAccount = dbContext.CardAccounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CardNumber == cardNumber);
    try
    {
        if (currentAccount == null)
        {
              throw new ArgumentException("Invalid card number.");
        }

        if (currentAccount.CardPIN != cardPIN)
        {
           throw new ArgumentException("Invalid pin number.");
        }

        if (currentAccount.CardCash < money)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Insufficient funds.");
        }

        currentAccount.CardCash -= money;

       var transactionLog = new TransactionHistory();
       transactionLog.CardNumber = cardNumber;
       transactionLog.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;
       transactionLog.Ammount = money;

       dbContext.TransactionHistory.Add(transactionLog);

       dbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      outputProvider.PrintLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

When you call the `SaveChanges` method, EF creates a transaction to save all the operations that you did before.

Also, you don't need to worry if the internal transaction fail. `DbContextTransaction.Dispose` method will be called in the end of the `using` block and it will automatically rollback the transaction if the transaction is not successfully committed.

Use a transaction when you need to do multiple calls to SaveChanges:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    // Do something 
    context.SaveChanges();
    // Do something else
    context.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I'll post the comment again in case you havent saw it yet. => 
It is a sample coursework project. The whole idea of the system is to grasp the concept of transactions. That's the reason I NEED to use a transaction in the withdraw method!